# child classes not toggling in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am new to jquery trying to add css classes using jquery to style html, but here inner child's are not toggling...[here is my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/venumadhav/v6u54Lzm/1/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#styling").click(function() {
    //header
    $("header").find("h2").toggleClass("heading");
    //navigation
    $(".list-items").find("li").toggleClass("list");
    //content styles
    $(".content > div:nth-child(1)").toggleClass("lft-cnt");
    $(".content > div:nth-child(2)").toggleClass("rgt-cnt");
    $(".rgt-cnt").find(">, div").toggleClass("image");
    $(".testimonials").children().toggleClass("slide");
    $(".slide:nth-child(2n + 1)").css("background-color", "#bbf");
  });
});
```

```css
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }
    .container {
      width: 630px;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    header {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100px;
      background: skyblue;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .heading {
      line-height: 100px;
      text-transform: Capitalize;
      font-family: tahoma;
    }
    ul {
      width: 100%;
    }
    .list {
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 10px 43px;
      background: white;
    }
    .content {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      margin-top: 20px;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .lft-cnt {
      width: 50%;
      float: left;
      height: auto;
      padding: 0 10px 10px 10px;
    }
    .rgt-cnt {
      width: 49%;
      float: left;
      height: auto;
      padding: 0 10px 10px 10px;
      text-align: center;
      position: relative;
    }
    .testimonials {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .slide {
      width: 130px;
      height: 100px;
      font-family: tahoma;
      text-align: center;
      display: inline-block;
      background-color: #FAD3D3;
    }
    footer {
      width: 100%;
      height: 40px;
      background: black;
      margin: 15px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .copyright {
      color: grey;
      line-height: 40px;
      font-family: tahoma;
      font-size: 14px;
    }
    .styles {
      width: 100%;
      height: 70px;
      text-align: center;
      position: relative;
    }
    .btn-wrapper {
      width: 100%;
      right: 50%;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 50%;
      transform: translate(50%, 50%);
    }
    button {
      background: #fff;
      border: 2px solid #000;
      padding: 10px 8px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .image {
      width: 150px;
      height: 150px;
      background: orange;
      position: absloute;
      right: 50%: bottom: 50%;
      transform: translate(50%, 50%);
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <h2>heading</h2>
  </header>
  <div class="list-items">
    <ul>
      <li>home</li>
      <li>home</li>
      <li>home</li>
      <li>home</li>
      <li>home</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div>
      <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution.</p>
      <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution.</p>
      <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution.</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>
        image
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="testimonials">
    <div>slide-one</div>
    <div>slide-two</div>
    <div>slide-three</div>
    <div>slide-four</div>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <div class="copyright">copyright@2016</div>
  </footer>
  <div class="styles">
    <div class="btn-wrapper">
      <button id="styling">style</button>
      <!-- <button id="nav">Navigation-styles</button>
            <button id="cnt">content-styles</button>
            <button id="ftr">footer-styles</button> -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am new to jquery trying to add css classes using jquery to style html, but here inner child's are not toggling...[here is my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/venumadhav/v6u54Lzm/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  problem is that although you're toggling the `slide` class, the style added using pseudo element won't get toggled if you do `.css()`. The `.css()` modifies elements `style` attribute (see api reference: http://api.jquery.com/css/) and thus can't be toggled.

As a solution, you can have the following entry in your css file-

`.slide:nth-child(2n + 1) {
    background-color: #bbf;
}`

and remove the line `$(".slide:nth-child(2n + 1)").css("background-color", "#bbf");` from your js. This will do the trick